# Best Practice with Table jonction, entites

Tags: .net

I search the best practice for create an entity on a kind of situation.

There's a sample:

We have 4 tables in a database.

```
Table Server
id
name
...

Table Environment
id
name

Table Application
id
name
...

Table JCT_Application_Server_Environment
idApplication
idServer
idEnvironment
```

We have 3 tables linked by 1 table(JCT_Application_Server_Environment)

my system (in asp.net) need to show the list of "Server" for an application.

So, should I use an entity like :

***V1***

```
class JCT_Application_Server_Environment
public idApplication
public idServer
public idEnvironment
```

and for each item I load the server and environment.
that will be "difficult" with a datagrid to load every time.
For my purpose, I think that's not the good things to do.

---

Or did its better to create an entity  :

***V2***

```
class JCT_Application_Server_Environment
    public ApplicationName
    public ServeurName
    public EnvironmentName
```

You have what you need.
Simple, take the minimum. 
If you need more, take more time to do.

If you have a lot of properties, its will take time to do the entity. And every properties are already created in another entites (the original Application/Server/environment).

---

Or maybe

***V3***

```
class JCT_Application_Server_Environment
    public Application //As Application entity
    public Server     //As Server entity
    public Environment //As Environment entity

Sub New(row as datarow) //each New do a GetElementById on Database
   me.Application = New Application(row("idApplication"))
   me.Server = New Server (row("idServer "))
   me.Environment = New Environment (row("idEnvironment "))
```

take time to load at first but get what you need and maybe more.
Datagrid just need to know to take the sub value (Server.Name/Environment.Name)

---

The first one is used mostly on import/export system. for webView its not the version I usely used because I prefer to go easy on gridview databound.

The second is used more often but the entity is for only one thing. 1 entity for 1 gridview. The actual situation fit for the second version. I just want to know if its better the second or the third. What Developper with .net experience uselly do.

If you have any other options, you can post-it as an answer.

---

For my actual project, I decided to use V3 but only for the container. the data is Fill by a DAL.

Dal do something like

```
function GetList() as List(Of JCT_Application_Server_Environment)

Get List of Application_Server_Environment containing id's

for each item
grab Application, Server and Envirenment by id
create a new JCT_Application_Server_Environment with those 3
add to list of JCT_Application_Server_Environment

return list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you have laid out here I feel approach the problem from a data-centric point of view. The table schema you have designed is in 3rd Normal Form (3NF) and *arguably* is a standard way of modelling the data in a relational database.

The rub comes when attempting to model this in an application entity as there is an impedance mismatch between how the data is modeled in the database and how you would like to model it in the application. The 3NF data modelling means that in order to hydrate one or more of your entities (I'm going to call them `Process` entities for lack of a better word, as they represent an application running on a server in an environment) there are going to be inner joins between 3 tables to get the required data. On top of this, there might be other fields in those three tables that sometimes we want to return and other times we don't (we might not need them), compounding the problem.

Now I don't know anything about your application, but looking at this, I would be inclined to model this from an application (and hence entity) centric point of view. The above problem is largely the reason why Object Relational Mapping (ORM) frameworks such as **[NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/)** and **[Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework)** exist. Now, this *could* all be mapped to one table but I have some questions:

1. Is there a fixed set of environments?
2. Is there a fixed set of servers?
3. Is there a fixed set of applications?

If these are all true, the simplest approach may be to define an `enum` for each and include the three enums in an entity

```
public class Process
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Environment Environment { get; set; }
    public Application Application{ get; set; }
    public Server Server { get; set; }
}
```

Then have a `Processes` table to store these values in.

If any of server, application or environment will change, then I would ask how often will they change?

If they change infrequently, then it may be possible to do the simple approach still and maintain the application/database as necessary.

If they change frequently, then a more normalized database structure as you have suggested may be the way to go. Now you could write the raw ADO.NET to pull the data, but I would suggest looking at something like **[Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)**, **[Simple.Data](http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/)** or **[Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive)** to help with this and then binding your DataGrid to a collection of your entities. Depending on what fields you need from each table and how frequently that data is needed, you might end up with several different types of sparse model to represent partial data from the database, or you might choose to return `dynamic` types and *know* what properties you can access for a given context, or you might return fully hydrated entities each time. Each approach has trade-offs in terms of performance usefulness and maintainability and which you choose really depends on knowing more about the application.

I hope I've raised some interesting questions to think about and given some useful suggestions as to how to handle this somewhat tricky subject.

Comment: tanks for all your answer. I will look more at the entity framework for my next project. You ask for fixed set: No, All data come from database, I do not know what there is inside. The question is not how to retrieve the data from database. I got everything on my DAL's. I know that each approach got " terms of performance usefulness and maintainability" , I just look at a better way to make my code more "respectful" I guess.

Comment: and tanks for "Object Relational Mapping", the Theory behind the code. I will look at that, it could help me.

Comment: @forX I hope it helps. At this point in time, my opinion would be NHibernate over Entity Framework; I think it is currently more feature-rich and mature. I'd be inclined to go for your V3 and monitor performance.